# core graphic not drawing gradient color in cliped rect

Tags: objective-c

this pieces of code won't work, i don't know why. 
just create a trangle and clip then draw gradient

```
// create contect and save
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // create path
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 20, rect.size.height - 20);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, rect.size.width / 2, 20);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, rect.size.width - 20, rect.size.height - 20);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
        CGContextAddPath(context, path);
        CGContextClip(context);
        // create gradient
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        NSArray *colorArr = @[
                             (id)[UIColor blackColor],
                             (id)[UIColor whiteColor],
                             ];
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colorArr, NULL);
        // rlease gradinet
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2,rect.size.height - 20), CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2, 20), 0);
        // restore context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

After upload this question, i find my error, the color should be CGColor,
like this [UIColor redColor].cgColor.